# What is X if I know y and Gamma(X)=y?

Tags: gamma-function, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for X if I know y and:

Gamma(X)=y

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here:http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-04/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2.pdf

Comment: Thanks but can you please mention the approach in simple terms, In addition, this article needs user and pass:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial for starting $$\Gamma(x)=y\implies x=\Gamma^{(-1)}(y)$$ Now, have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0) and admire the simplicity and beauty of David W. Cantrell's solution. It is really impressive.

Defining

$$L(y)= \log \left(\frac{c+y}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)$$ $$\Gamma^{(-1)}(y)=\frac{L(y)}{W\left(\frac{L(y)}{e}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}$$ (using $c=0.036534$) or more rigorously $$c=\frac {\sqrt{2\pi}} e- k$$ $k$ being the positive zero of the digamma function $(\approx 1.461632)$.

Comment: Beautiful, I really appreciate this, Thanks a million Claude.

Comment: @mohsenhs. You are welcome ! I did not do anything except telling that Cantrell did the work !