# what is $\alpha$ in $10=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+2/\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)^2}+1$

Tags: gamma-function

I am trying to solve the following equation by finding '$\alpha$', but unfortunately I can't go further, I appreciate any help.

$10=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+2/\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)^2} +1$

Since $\Gamma(1+x)=x!$ and by considering $x=1/\alpha$

$10=\dfrac{(2x)!}{(x!*x!)}$

and then?

and I know that how I can find x if I know y in
$\Gamma(x)=y\implies x=\Gamma^{(-1)}(y)$ from [What is X if I know y and Gamma(X)=y?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015680/what-is-x-if-i-know-y-and-gammax-y)
, but I can not get to this point.

@Claude, Thank you for your support, I think I did it ( in R by uniroot),

`ufun <- function(x,up2) { uniroot(function(z) ((gamma(1+2*z)/gamma(1+z)^2-x))  ,c(0,up2))$root}
irr <- 0
up2=0.009
while(irr<=0)
{
up2=up2+0.001
 irr <- NA 
 irr=try(  ufun(3,up2),silent=T)
 if(!is.numeric(irr)) irr <- 0
else
print(irr)
}`

Comment: WolframAlpha gives two solutions of $\alpha=-2.0773\dots$ and $\alpha= 0.426775\dots$.

Comment: Thank you Argon, but what is the approach?

Comment: This used purely numerical methods. I don't think you should expect an elementary closed form.

Comment: Thanks Argon for your consideration.

Comment: Note that the Gamma -> factorial identity you give only works positive integers. It doesn't apply to fractions.

Comment: Your method will be extremely slow. Have a look to my update. Just code Newton method. In $R$, you access the digamma function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in comments, numerical methods are required.

As you suggested, changing variable $\alpha=\frac 1x$ makes the equation to be $$9=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+2x)}{\Gamma(1+x)^2}$$ It would be better conditionned taking logarithms to look for the zero of  $$f(x)=\log\left(\Gamma(1+2x) \right)-2\log\left(\Gamma(1+x) \right)-\log(9)$$ By inspection $$f(0)=-\log (9)\qquad f(1)=-\log \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)\qquad  f(2)=-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\qquad f(3)=\log \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)$$ So, the root is between $2$ and $3$.

Now, using Taylor around $x=2$ gives $$f(x)=(\log (6)-\log (9))+\frac{7 (x-2)}{6}+\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{115}{72}\right)
   (x-2)^2+O\left((x-2)^3\right)$$ Solving the quadratic leads to $x\approx 2.34274$.

Using Taylor around $x=3$ gives $$f(x)=(\log (20)-\log (9))+\frac{37 (x-3)}{30}+\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{973}{600}\right)
   (x-3)^2+O\left((x-3)^3\right)$$ Solving the quadratic leads to $x\approx 2.34445$.

It is probably sufficient (the "exact" solution being $x\approx 2.34315$).

**Edit**

If you are very lazy, using the values for $x=1,2,3$ to which correspond $y=2,6,20$ write the equation of a parabola. This should give $$y=5x^2-11x+8$$; so, if you want $y=9$, you need to solve $5x^2-11x-1=0$ the positive solution being $x=\frac{11+\sqrt{141}}{10} \approx 2.28743$ which gives a "reasonable" approximation.

**Update**

If you need to solve accurately for $x$ the equation $$a=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+2x)}{\Gamma(1+x)^2}$$ numerical methods are required and Newton would be the simplest, assuming a "reasonable" starting point.

However, since the function is varying very fast, I would again suggest to search for the zero of $$f(x)=\log\left(\Gamma(1+2x) \right)-2\log\left(\Gamma(1+x) \right)-\log(a)$$ $$f'(x)=2\left( \psi (2 x+1)-\psi (x+1)\right)$$ $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Concerning the starting point, for "small" values of $x$, we could use the Padé approximant built around $x=0$ to get $$\log\left(\Gamma(1+2x) \right)-2\log\left(\Gamma(1+x) \right)\approx \frac{\pi ^4 x^2}{72 \zeta (3)x+6 \pi ^2}$$ which, for $a=9$ would give $x_0=2.48892$ and the converge would be quite fast as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.4889169127815621492 \\
 1 & 2.3437475740831992170 \\
 2 & 2.3431531513648521187 \\
 3 & 2.3431531406628368140 \\
 4 & 2.3431531406628368105 
 \end{array}
\right)$$

This approximation is quite good for $0\leq x \leq 2$ (that is to say for $1 \leq a \leq 6$).

For larger values, derived from a linear regression for $2\leq x \leq 13$ (that is to say for $6 \leq a \leq 10^{7}$), we could use $$\log\left(\Gamma(1+2x) \right)-2\log\left(\Gamma(1+x) \right)\approx 1.31146 x-0.973398$$ which, for $a=9$ would give $x_0=2.41763$.

All of that would make the solution reached very fast even for high accuracy.

Let us try it for $a=123456$; the iterates would then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 9.6730500000000000000 \\
 1 & 9.6984246472567273657 \\
 2 & 9.6984234280990188021 \\
 3 & 9.6984234280990159973 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks Claude, I really appreciate your consideration. Could you please explain briefly how you find out that the root is between 2 and 3, and what Taylor is referring to? Is it referring to 'Quadratic Taylor Polynomial Approximations'?

Comment: @mohsenhs. Inspection first (as written in the answer). Then Taylor series.

Comment: Many thanks, Much appreciated

Comment: :) Thank you Claude, I am working on implementing this in R as I need to do this for about 10000 times. I will keep you posted

Comment: @mohsenhs. What is changing from run to run ? I think that we could build a pretty good approximation if what you need is to solve for $x$ equation $a=\dfrac{\Gamma(1+2x)}{\Gamma(1+x)^2}+1$.

Comment: Thank a lot Claude for your nice explanation